# Why would a fresh install of node.js and protractor error out with `execvp` No such file or directory?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I've installed several versions of node.js and protractor, then followed the instructions to update the webdriver, but none of the combinations I've come up with successfully start up the webdriver.

A few helpful details:

- On Ubuntu 64-bit
- Tried node.js v0.10.15 and v0.10.26
- Tried protractor 0.18.1 and 0.19.0

Here are the commands I've run, and the corresponding error (after installing protractor):

```
$ webdriver-manager update
Updating selenium standalone
downloading https://selenium.googlecode.com/files/selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar...
Updating chromedriver
downloading https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.8/chromedriver_linux64.zip...
chromedriver_2.8.zip downloaded to /home/<user>/.nvm/v0.10.26/lib/node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver_2.8.zip
selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar downloaded to /home/<user>/.nvm/v0.10.26/lib/node_modules/protractor/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar


$ webdriver-manager start
execvp(): No such file or directory
seleniumProcess.pid: 4567

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:988:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:779:34)
```

Answer (score 3):

Turns out I needed to install the Java Development Kit (JDK), then it worked fine.

Comment: `openjdk-7-jre-headless` seems to be enough and has less dependencies than `openjdk-7-jre`